# Pathway of lowest values between 2 points in 2D heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, path-finding

I was wondering if I could get some concept ideas from you all before spending too much time on this.

I have a (X,Y,Z) heatmap file showing the energy (Z value) of multiple XY coordinates.

```
X,Y,Z
-8.000000,0.000000,30
-7.920000,0.000000,30
-7.840000,0.000000,30
-7.760000,0.000000,30
-7.680000,0.000000,30
(...)
7.680000,25.000000,30
7.760000,25.000000,30
7.840000,25.000000,30
7.920000,25.000000,30
8.000000,25.000000,30
```

I would like to determine possible pathways between 2 points in the XY space. These pathways should consist of a series of XY coordinates with the lowest Z values necessary in order to connect the selected regions.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest looking into A* pathfinding algorithms. Game programmers use it as a baseline pathfinding algorithm.  I learned it a few years ago from this blog:  https://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/ 

A* will not get you the globally optimal path, but something that is locally the shortest path.

Comment: Thanks @Conic . It seems that ```pip install pathfinding``` also gives me a A* algorithm that I can build up from.

If I need a globally optimal path, which algorithm would you suggest?

Comment: although significantly less efficient, the globally optimal path between any two points can be computed using Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: "with the lowest Z values necessary" can you clarify this a bit more? Do you wish to minimize the average height of the path (regardless of how long it is), minimize the *maximum* height of the path, or minimize the sum of heights underneath the path (or something else entirely)? E.g. consider that these three objectives will pick differently between path candidates `[1, 1, 1, 1, 10]`, `[2, 10]` and `[8, 8, 8, 8, 8]`.